# How to Convert XML to JSON in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I would like to convert an XML column into a JSON string.

XML:

```
<Policies>
  <Policy>
    <GroupUserName>testX</GroupUserName>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <Name>Browser</Name>
        <Description>May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>Content Manager</Name>
        <Description>May manage content in the Report Server.  This includes folders, reports and resources.</Description>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
  </Policy>
  <Policy>
    <GroupUserName>meme</GroupUserName>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <Name>Browser</Name>
        <Description>May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>My Reports</Name>
        <Description>May publish reports and linked reports; manage folders, reports and resources in a users My Reports folder.</Description>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
  </Policy>
  <Policy>
    <GroupUserName>test980706</GroupUserName>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <Name>Browser</Name>
        <Description>May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports.</Description>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
  </Policy>
  <Policy>
    <GroupUserName>Admin</GroupUserName>
    <Roles>
      <Role>
        <Name>Browser</Name>
        <Description>May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>Content Manager</Name>
        <Description>May manage content in the Report Server.  This includes folders, reports and resources.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>My Reports</Name>
        <Description>May publish reports and linked reports; manage folders, reports and resources in a users My Reports folder.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>Publisher</Name>
        <Description>May publish reports and linked reports to the Report Server.</Description>
      </Role>
      <Role>
        <Name>Report Builder</Name>
        <Description>May view report definitions.</Description>
      </Role>
    </Roles>
  </Policy>
</Policies>
```

JSON:

```
{
"Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"InheritParentPolicy": false"Policies": [
    {
        "GroupUserName": "testX",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "Admin",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            },
            {
                "Name": "Content Manager",
                "Description": "May manage content in the Report Server.  This includes folders, reports and resources."
            },
            {
                "Name": "My Reports",
                "Description": "May publish reports and linked reports; manage folders, reports and resources in a users My Reports folder."
            },
            {
                "Name": "Publisher",
                "Description": "May publish reports and linked reports to the Report Server."
            },
            {
                "Name": "Report Builder",
                "Description": "May view report definitions."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "meme",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            },
            {
                "Name": "My Reports",
                "Description": "May publish reports and linked reports; manage folders, reports and resources in a users My Reports folder."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "test980706",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "ETL",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "Artin",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "mamad",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "Salour",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "Zargar",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "AUser",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "GroupUserName": "TUser",
        "Roles": [
            {
                "Name": "Browser",
                "Description": "May view folders, reports and subscribe to reports."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting us know, and good luck. If you get stuck, please do ask a question, showing us your attempts and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: My recommendation: don't. The problem is that T-SQL wants fixed, pre-defined result sets. This means you have to shred the XML into table(s) using the various methods available for that (`.nodes()`, `.query()`, `.value()`), and *then* you could reconstitute those tables back into JSON (the easy part, `FOR JSON`). This is massively unwieldy, and pure string replacement isn't much better either (due to T-SQL's limited function in this area). If you want to convert XML to JSON, the best place to do it is "anywhere but SQL Server itself". Let client code take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
SELECT 
    d.value('GroupUserName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')  AS GroupUserName
    ,(SELECT 
        f.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Name'
        ,f.value('Description[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Description'
        FROM c.d.nodes('Roles/Role') AS e(f)            
        FOR JSON PATH) 'Roles'
FROM @xml.nodes('/Policies/Policy') AS c(d)
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: Use the following link when using an attribute : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728704/sql-2016-converting-xml-to-json